# como puedo evaluar un dato devuelto por el método $.get de Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

realizo una petición del tipo GET cada 500ms a través de setInterval, los datos devueltos los voy escribiendo en diferentes divs en mi código HTML.

Código :

```
setInterval(function(){
        $.get("data_recv.html", function(result){
            datos= result.split(",");
            var divs=["#variable1","#variable2","#variable3","#variable4","#variable6"];
            for(i in datos){
                $(divs[i]).text(datos[i]);
            }
        });
    },500);
```

Como podría evaluar un dato devuelto por GET :

Ejemplo:

lo que se recupere en el índice inicial del array datos[0] se escribirá en el  de mi código html. Teniendo en cuenta q el valor recuperado por datos[0] es un string con el valor "verde", como podría tomar dicho valor devuelto y evaluarlo en una condición if para posteriormente modificar un el estilo de un elemento.

ejemplo :

```
if(datos[0]=="verde"){
 $("#circle").css("background","red");
}
```

He intentado evaluar el dato devuelto fuera del método $.get() y no he me ha funcionado.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Finalmente no conseguí resultado positivo alguno. Por aquí comparto mi último código esperando puedan ayudarme con sus comentarios y sugerencias.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
            /*$('#recibir').click*/setInterval(function(){
                $.get("data_recv.html", function(data,status,xhr){
                    datos= data.split(",");
                    var variables=["#variable1","#variable2","#variable3","#variable4",
                    "#variable6","#variable7"];
                        for(i in datos){
                        $(variables[i]).text(datos[i]);
                        }
                    $('#estatus').text("datos recibidos:"+ data +"status:"+status+" "+xhr);
                    procesarDatos(datos); //paso los datos adquiridos del servidor
                });
            },500);
        });

        function procesarDatos(datos){
            $('#imprime').text(datos[4]);

            if (datos[4]==="verde") {
                $('#circle').css("background","green");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

En la función procesarDatos(datos), me encargo de pasar los datos devueltos por el servidor. Fuera del $.get(), creo la función y me aseguro en primer lugar imprimir el resultado devuelto en el índice datos[4]. El resultado devuelto es un string con el valor "verde". Al realizar la impresión se muestra en pantalla correctamente el valor devuelto "verde", pero sucede que en la siguiente línea de código evalúo dicho valor para modificar el estilo de un elemento.

```
if (datos[4]==="verde") {
                $('#circle').css("background","green");
            }
```

Desde consola consigo consultar el valor de datos[4] y este me indica q el valor devuelto es = "verde". Pero no logro entender por que la condición no me responde y modifica el estilo de mi objeto con id="circle".

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o sugerencia.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Las peticiones de ajax son asincronas lo que significa que cuando hayas recibido la respuesta del servidor, la ejecucion del metodo que hizo la peticion ya terminado. Por eso debes de hacer la comprobacion dentro del metodo:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("data_recv.html", function(result) {
        datos = result.split(",");
        var divs = ["#variable1", "#variable2", "#variable3", "#variable4", "#variable6"];
        for (i in datos) {
            $(divs[i]).text(datos[i]);
        }

          if(datos[0]=="verde"){ 
                $("#circle").css("background","red");
           }
    });
}, 500);
```

**ACTUALIZACION:**

Si verdaderamente necesitas evaluar la respuesta fuera del `$.get`, entonces define una funcion dentro de la funcion que se ejecutara siempre que el servidor de una respuesta y ahi entonces podras hacer lo que necesites:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("data_recv.html", function(result) {
        datos = result.split(",");
        var divs = ["#variable1", "#variable2", "#variable3", "#variable4", "#variable6"];
        for (i in datos) {
            $(divs[i]).text(datos[i]);
        }
        if(procesarDatos != undefined)
           procesarDatos(datos); // este metodo se ejecutara siempre que el server de una respuesta

          if(datos[0]=="verde"){ 
                $("#circle").css("background","red");
           }
    });
}, 500);
```

Entonces defines la funcion y cuando se ejecute, es porque el servidor retorno datos:

```
function procesarDatos(datos)
{
   // procesas los datos aqui
}
```

Comment: Es posible rescatar el valor devuelto por el servidor y sacarlo fuera del método $.get para evaluarlo ?

Comment: Si es posible pero eso no te asegurara que tendras el valor actualizado o siquiera asignado.

Comment: Podría usted brindarme la solución para rescatar dicho valor devuelto y evaluarlo fuera del método $.get()

Comment: Mira mi respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia pero no me quedó claro tu actualización, agradecería lo puedas volver a plantear con las variables o datos que yo estoy definiendo. Mil Gracias.

Comment: La idea es que cuando el servidor responda, se ejecute una funcion que recibira la variable datos. Esto es para asegurar que la variable datos haya sido asignada y para siempre obtener el ultimo valor la variable datos.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve probando este código y funciona.

A mi me gusta escribir código que controle cualquier posibilidad y adaptándolo siempre a las indicaciones de los creadores.

En este caso [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) indica que es recomendable usar `done`, `fail` y demás familiares en las peticiones del tipo Ajax. `done` sería en sí como una función propia y puedes manejar los resultados exitosos desde allí, o bien puedes pasarle los datos a una función fuera del get, como muestra el código de más abajo.

Las partes más importantes están comentadas en el mismo código.

Entonces, aquí vamos:

### HTML en el origen:

El último div nos servirá para informar sobre posibles situaciones impredecibles

```
<div id="variable1"></div>
<div id="variable2"></div>
<div id="variable3"></div>
<div id="variable4"></div>
<div id="variable5"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(function() { //Asegurar que el DOM está cargado 
    setInterval(function(){
        var url="ok.html"; //Cambiar por el nombre de tu HTML o PHP
        var peticion = $.get(url, function(data) 
        {
            console.log( "Petición enviada" );
        },"html") //Indicamos que queremos los datos en HTML

        .done(function(data) 
        {
            console.log( data);
            mostrarDatos(data); //pasamos resultado de respuesta fuera de la petición get

        })

         //Este fragmento correrá si hay error en la petición Ajax
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) 
        {
            console.log( "error en la petición ajax:" + textStatus );
            $("#info").html("<p>Error Ajax: " + textStatus + "</p>");

        })     
    },500);

});


//Función llamada desde dentro de la petición get       
function mostrarDatos(data)
{
        console.log("Mostrando datos usando otra función: ");

        //Evaluamos que el html no esté vacío
        if (data)
        {

            datos= data.split(",");
            var divs=["#variable1","#variable2","#variable3","#variable4","#variable5"];
            for(i in datos)
            {
                $(divs[i]).text(datos[i]);
            }

        }else{

            $("#info").html("<p>No hay nada en el archivo de la petición get</p>");

        }

}
```

### HTML en el destino

Yo lo he llamado `ok.html`, te toca a ti cambiarlo por el tuyo.

Su contenido con datos de prueba es:

```
Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5
```

### Resultado

En pantalla

```
Dato1
Dato2
Dato3
Dato4
```

En consola:

```
[Log] Petición enviada (test.php, line 17)
[Log] Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5 (test.php, line 22)
[Log] Mostrando datos usando otra función:  (test.php, line 39)
[Log] Petición enviada (test.php, line 17)
[Log] Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5 (test.php, line 22)
[Log] Mostrando datos usando otra función:  (test.php, line 39)
[Log] Petición enviada (test.php, line 17)
[Log] Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5 (test.php, line 22)
....
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.